# Matplotlib plots 2D shapes instead of 1D lines

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, time-series

I'm trying to plot the Treasury Yield curves. I've got the data in the following pandas data frame:
[image]

So, basically I want to plot the 3 columns of the data frame against index and want to have 3 lines. But when I try to do so, instead of the lines I get 2D shapes which overlap with each other, like this:

[image]

I tried using both `df.plot()` from Pandas and usual `plt.plot()` commands, but they give the same result. How can I make 1D lines from these 2D shapes?

Comment: Where is the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the plot you show, those are *actually* lines, but they are so close to each other that it seems there is a colored area.

Fake dataframe creation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start = '1990-01-02', end = '2020-12-31', freq = 'D')})
df['DGS1'] = 10*np.random.random(len(df))
df['DGS10'] = 10*np.random.random(len(df))
df['DGS5'] = 10*np.random.random(len(df))
df = df.set_index('date')
```

Plotting:

```
df.plot()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Zoom in a casual region:

```
plt.xlim('2003-03-07', '2003-08-04')
```

[image]

Zoom again:

```
plt.xlim('2003-04-07', '2003-04-22')
```

[image]

---

You could keep your dataframe as is, if you are ok with zooming in some regions of interest, otherwise you can apply a re-sampling of your data with [**`pandas.DataFrame.resample`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html). Pay attention that this operation will change your original data, so you have to be carefull about interpreting the plot you will get.
A working example could be to resample the dataframe with a frequency of 1 month and calculate the mean over each month:

```
df = df.resample('1M').mean()
```

[image]